# Comparar valores de duas tabelas em uma Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, tsql

Tenho uma aplicação que lista em uma grid arquivos que estão registrados na tabela

> SCF_DocumentoProcessoCompra

Porém, agora eu preciso listar somente se este arquivo também existir na tabela

> SCF_ARQUIVO_UPLOAD

O que a aplicação faz é buscar o arquivo na primeira tabela pelo ID do tipo do arquivo e listar. O que ela precisa fazer agora é buscar o ID, pegar o caminho do documento que fica na coluna Path_Documento da primeira tabela depois comparar com o CaminhoParcial, se tiver resultado, lista todos.

Estou fazendo a consulta assim, porém não esta listando nada:

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[sp_RecuperaDocumentosProcesso] --2

@id_ProcessoCompra INT

AS

SELECT
        id_ProcessoCompra
        ,Path_Documento
FROM SCF_DocumentoProcessoCompra DPC
LEFT JOIN SCF_ARQUIVO_UPLOAD SAP
    ON DPC.id_DocumentoProcessoCompra = SAP.Id_Arquivo

    WHERE DPC.Path_Documento LIKE '%' + SAP.CaminhoParcial + '%'
```

Create das 2 tabelas:

```
USE [SCF2_HOMOLOG_325]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[SCF_DocumentoProcessoCompra]    Script Date: 24/01/2018 16:42:59 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SCF_DocumentoProcessoCompra](
    [id_DocumentoProcessoCompra] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [id_ModeloDocumento] [int] NULL,
    [Desc_DocumentoProcessoCompra] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Path_Documento] [varchar](300) NULL,
    [Dt_PublicacaoDocumento] [datetime] NULL,
    [Dt_CadastroDocumento] [datetime] NULL,
    [USR_CadastroDocumento] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [id_ProcessoCompra] [int] NULL,
    [id_TipoDocumento] [int] NULL,
    [FormatoDocumento] [smallint] NULL,
    [Texto_FinalDocumento] [text] NULL,
    [id_TipoModeloDocumento] [int] NULL,
    [ID_TIPOARQUIVO] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK__SCF_DocumentoPro__29572725] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id_DocumentoProcessoCompra] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[SCF_DocumentoProcessoCompra]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK__SCF_Docum__id_Pr__55009F39] FOREIGN KEY([id_ProcessoCompra])
REFERENCES [dbo].[SCF_ProcessoCompra] ([id_ProcessoCompra])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[SCF_DocumentoProcessoCompra] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK__SCF_Docum__id_Pr__55009F39]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[SCF_DocumentoProcessoCompra]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK__SCF_Docum__id_Ti__55F4C372] FOREIGN KEY([id_TipoDocumento])
REFERENCES [dbo].[SCF_TipoDocumento] ([id_TipoDocumento])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[SCF_DocumentoProcessoCompra] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK__SCF_Docum__id_Ti__55F4C372]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[SCF_DocumentoProcessoCompra]  WITH CHECK ADD FOREIGN KEY([ID_TIPOARQUIVO])
REFERENCES [dbo].[SCF_TiposDeArquivos] ([ID_TIPOARQUIVO])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[SCF_DocumentoProcessoCompra]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_SCF_DocProcesso_ModeloDocumento] FOREIGN KEY([id_ModeloDocumento])
REFERENCES [dbo].[SCF_ModeloDocumentos] ([id_ModeloDocumento])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[SCF_DocumentoProcessoCompra] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_SCF_DocProcesso_ModeloDocumento]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[SCF_DocumentoProcessoCompra]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_SCF_id_TipoModeloDocumento] FOREIGN KEY([id_TipoModeloDocumento])
REFERENCES [dbo].[SCF_TipoModeloDocumento] ([id_TipoModeloDocumento])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[SCF_DocumentoProcessoCompra] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_SCF_id_TipoModeloDocumento]
GO



USE [SCF2_HOMOLOG_325]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[SCF_ARQUIVO_UPLOAD]    Script Date: 24/01/2018 16:42:14 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SCF_ARQUIVO_UPLOAD](
    [Id_Arquivo] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [CaminhoParcial] [varchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [ArquivoBinario] [varbinary](max) NOT NULL,
    [Dt_HoraUpload] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Id_Usuario] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_SCF_Arquivo_Upload] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id_Arquivo] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[SCF_ARQUIVO_UPLOAD]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_SCF_Arquivo_Upload_ACS_Usuario1] FOREIGN KEY([Id_Usuario])
REFERENCES [dbo].[ACS_Usuario] ([id_Usuario])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[SCF_ARQUIVO_UPLOAD] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_SCF_Arquivo_Upload_ACS_Usuario1]
GO
```

Comment: Primeiro mude o left para um join de resto sem a tabela completa (create) não tem muito oq fazer

Comment: Editei o post principal!